# Should I use a Model or Not for my Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to RoR and hope I'm not in over my head here.  So I currently have a `user`, `product` and 'order` models.  My site just to give some context would be like using a paid Craigslist.  You pay Craigslist upfront a flat fee (order), and then you can create your listing on their site (product).

My question is the flat fee portion of the site (let's call it packages) and whether to use a model or not?  Currently there are 3 packages with 6 options.  (eg - A $10/mth or $100/yr, B $20/mth,$200/yr, C $30/mth, $300/yr)

I assume if a model is not used, some type of JS is probably used, which I'm not super comfortable with yet.  Any thoughts on what would be the best practice approach to this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with setting up a MVC and seeding the database with the fixed prices for each package.  Then in the create form, I added a hidden_tag that identified which package price should be passed to the Charges model to effectively charge the right price depending on the package chosen.